# kdenlive: selecting multiple nodes in a region (rotoscoping)

Tags: kdenlive

I'm trying to blur a region of a video through rotoscoping (using Kdenlive-16.12.2-x86_64.AppImage on Ubuntu 16.04).
This region -in my video it coincides with a face- moves in time.
I'm wondering if it is possible to select the multiple nodes defining the region, in order to move them all together when creating new keyframes.

[image: nodes defining a region]

Right now I've to move each node separately, it seems not possible to select all nodes in the same time.